# “I’m waiting for you...” or “I’m waiting you...”

Tags: grammar, difference

> I’m waiting for you to answer me on StackExchange.

Should I use *waiting for you* or *waiting you*? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I am waiting for you"* is grammatically correct. You may use *"I'm waiting"* but without using *"you"* afterwards.

Comment: +0.9 It may profit OP to be told that *wait* is an intransitive verb and cannot take a direct object.

Answer (score 3):

**Use a Preposition**

*Waiting* is an intransitive verb.  That means it does not<sup>1</sup> take a direct object.  There is no thing *directly* affected by the verb, as it is implied that the doer (subject) of the waiting is the one who is affected.  If you wish to indicate *why* the subject is waiting, you do so with a preposition - usually *for* but occasionally *on*  (see below).

So:

> **A:** She is waiting.  *[note: We already know what party is affected by there verb - **SHE** is]*
>
> **B:**  Why?
>
> **A:** She is waiting *for* a friend to arrive. *[The arrival of the friend tells us the circumstances under which the action was performed]*

<sup>1 <sub>I can think of two exceptions:  *Wait tables,* in which *wait* has a totally different meaning, and *wait your turn* which is a packaged phrase.</sub></sup>

---

**Which Preposition?**

*Waiting on* is sometimes used in American English.  It is more a regionalism than a socio-economic indicator.  You don't hear it much in the Pacific Northwest, where I live, but in Texas and the Deep South it is more common.

*Waiting on* sounded good enough to the Grammy award voters who named John Mayer's *Waiting on the World to Change* the "Best Male Pop Vocal."

There is extended discussion of the regional nature of this over on [English.se](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44452/wait-on-vs-wait-for)

My recommendation is that you use *wait for.*   While *waiting on* is common in some regions, it sounds very weird to people who are not from those regions, whereas everyone is comfortable with *wait for.*

Comment: The question wasn't whether to use "on" vs. "for", but whether to use a preposition at all. (Yes, the answer is obvious to a native speaker, but not so much to a learner, and unfortunately none of the answers so far have explained *why* the preposition is required.)

Comment: Also note British group _The Rolling Stones'_ 1981 song _Waiting on a Friend_

Comment: @Martha - You're right.  So obvious that my mind filled in the missing preposition in his question as _on._  Thanks - I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

You should use 'waiting for you'. It is a transitive phrase. This means that the verb (waiting) needs one or more words.

You could also say, 'waiting on you'.

Comment: "Waiting on you" is specifically American English.  In British English, I would "wait on you" if I were a waiter in a restaurant.

Comment: And *waiting on* is strictly colloquial, not acceptable in formal registers.

Comment: umm .. no. *Wait* is intransitive, which is why it requires a preposition phrase as a complement.

Comment: Unless I was serving you, I would not be waiting *on* you. Waiting *on* is used colloquially, but is not correct usage. [LINK to question about waiting *on*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115379/waiting-on-a-miracle/115387#115387)