# waiting ON a miracle?

Tags: meaning

Is this phrase correct?

> "Smoke and mirrors keep us waiting ON a miracle"
>   ("Let Me Love You" Justin Bieber)

looked up in the browser and found out that

to WAIT ON is to bring a meal for someone. And this meaning isn't suitable actually. I assume in this song "wait on" is used like "wait for a miracle" or "believe in a miracle". What can you tell me about it?

ADD:
Guys, really thank you for your help. Yeah, i agree with SimonH that first of all i need to learn proper English, which i really want to do and try to do. As i understand, "WAIT ON" can exist like "WAIT FOR" but only with my english-spoken friends. And i'd better avoid using it at school, moreover while i'm sitting my exams. THANK YOU AGAIN ;)

Comment: Song lyrics are not usually a good place to look for strictly correct grammar and usage, because they're written to sound good, not to be absolutely correct.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/44452/64632 where there is a lot of information.

Comment: If you're looking to improve proper English, please, never use "i", always "I".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Wait **on*** is a colloquial variant of *wait **for*** ; it is not acceptable in formal discourse.

In my experience the two are practically equivalent, except that there may be some slight tendency to prefer *on* when the wait is caused by a delay.

ADDED:
Just to clarify: in Bieber's song *wait on* is a colloquial variant of *wait for* something or someone. There is also a formal use of *wait on*, now virtually obsolete except in historical contexts, meaning "attend, hold oneself in readiness to serve" a superior. This is (for instance) the sense you encounter when Samuel Pepys writes "Thence to White Hall, and we waited on the Duke", or in the title "Lady-in-Waiting"; and this sense is the source of the still-current use with servers in a restaurant.

Comment: I also think that putting aside the constraints relating to it being "colloquial-only", AND the fact that even there it's not really my "default preposition" anyway, the chances of me saying *We're waiting **on** John* are greater if John *should* have arrived by now. As opposed to *We're waiting **for** John*, which would also be fine if it just so happens that John is the last of the group to arrive, but this isn't necessarily a matter of remark or concern. Given two alternative *equally credible* phrasings, it's always likely a distinction will arise over time.

Comment: Colloquial perhaps but the Rolling Stones recorded "Waiting on a Friend" in 1981, and you can find references that go much further back, including formal documents.  Perhaps it was wrong then as well.

Comment: @Andrew Well, you don't get much more colloquial than Mick & Co. And I think that you'll find that older formal uses of *waiting on* have the old meaning of *attending, holding oneself in readiness to serve*, which is broad sense from which the restaurant sense derives.

Comment: Thinking of how I have used "wait on", or heard it used, there may be a slight nuance of "impatience", as there is an unequal relationship and I have been forced to wait on someone else's convenience.   Although as others have said, being American, we use "incorrect" English all the time.

Comment: @Andrew Yes! Colloquial. Common. Yes. Proper English, not yet. The language changes constantly. When I was a child if I said "It's me." I'd have been in trouble at school. "It is I", was the only acceptable way to answer. I cannot remember the last time I used "It is I." in any conversation. No one uses it and now, few teachers would correct it.

Comment: Last time I heard it was in `'Allo, 'Allo!`. "It is I, LeClerk".  (Never mind - you have to be a Brit :)

Comment: @SimonH Heh, I am  Canadian -- love that show!

Comment: To my ear, "wait on" and "wait for" have slightly different meanings.  If one is waiting on a load of clothes, that would suggest that one is planning to stand next to the washing machine until it goes ding.  By contrast, waiting for a load of clothes would imply that there is some task one can't perform until the clothes are ready, but one might still be doing other things until that time.

Comment: Per the OED, *To wait on God* in the sense of having faith is a biblical phrase attested back to the sixteenth century, which may be relevant to the particular phrase; and the more general usage of *wait on* to mean something like *wait for in expectation of* is attested back to the late seventeenth ("We were forced to wait on him above half an hour"), in various registers, e.g., "'Wait on me!' he shouted" by Flannery O'Connor in 1955, but also "The nation waits on the railwaymen, to see if there will be a strike or not" in a 1960 *Observer* article.

Comment: *On* implies waiting with respect to something with agency to perform an action or attain a state or quality, whereas *for* is more passive. One waits *for* a holiday, but one waits *on* a person who is late and necessary for the holiday party to start.

Answer (score 3):

I would interpret the phrase "to wait on a miracle" as having a different meaning from "to wait for a miracle".  Which preposition is more appropriate would depend upon which meaning was intended.

At least by my interpretation, "to wait on object X" means "to watch for X to perform some expected action, while setting aside all other tasks".  By contrast, "to wait for object X" would mean that one is refraining from performing at least *some* task until X arrives, but does not imply that one is setting aside *all*--or even most--other tasks.

Waiting "on" a miracle would, metaphorically, suggest that there is a "miracle has occurred" light and one is focused exclusively on watching that light.  By contrast, waiting "for" a miracle would imply that there are some things one is expecting to do if/when the miracle occurs, but in the meantime one may do other things.

Comment: As a native speaker of American English, I agree completely with this distinction; it matches how I have heard the phrases used and how I would use them myself.  This distinction was also mentioned in [a comment on the accepted answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115379/waiting-on-a-miracle#comment232936_115381).

Answer (score 2):

My generation did not ever use 'wait on' unless it was specific to a server waiting on patrons in a restaurant or at a dinner party. A maid or butler would wait *on* you as well.

Now, most of us do not have maids or butlers and the only person 'waiting on' us is a wait person/ server.

I am waiting *for* the bus. I am waiting *for* spring.

In writing, waiting for is the accepted usage outside of the server/maid example. In speech, it is slang/colloquial (but not yet 'correct'*) for people to say, "I'm waiting on the bus." In writing that would mean you are literally waiting on the bus for an event to happen. "We waited on the bus, for the driver to arrive." This means we were inside, *on* the bus while we waited.

I said not correct* because if you are in a formal setting and trying to impress a potential employer or anyone important to you that you have some education, you should try not to use colloquialisms -- unless you fully understand them. It doesn't matter what those might be. Slang or colloquial speech is still unacceptable in some situations. Until you know those situations, I'd suggest you speak more formally. Everyone will understand you. ON EDIT: [Here is a link -- but you can google this easily.](http://www.grammarerrors.com/grammar/wait-onwait-for/)

I don't know if this is the same where you are from, but I automatically do not use swear words in many situations. I don't need to be told or have it explained. I just know not to swear at my teacher, the boss, a child, and so on. Other colloquialisms are similar. "Wassup?" might be perfectly acceptable to your group of friends, but totally unacceptable to your potential boss.

Justin Bieber is writing poetry/lyrics. There's a lot of leeway and license given to artists in their choice of phrasing and word usage.

Comment: Just how old are you?  The Rolling Stones recorded ["Waiting on a Friend"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKLVmBOOqVU) in 1981, and there are numerous references to "wait on" long before that, including this ["Report on the Royal Commission on Historical Manuscripts"](https://books.google.com/books?id=Tqw-AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA393&dq=%22wait+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie_9XP7rzRAhXM0FQKHWTPA_Q4ChDoAQgZMAA)  from 1879, "I am obliged to wait on the Prince Melkinbourg this morning to soil him a horse, and being afraid I could not wait on you time enough before you would send away your letters"

Comment: @Andrew: Those 19th century references use the sense of *wait on* meaning *serve*, not *wait for*.

Comment: I am in my sixties and those references you used mean "serve". Last time I checked, The Rolling Stones were artists and (though not anything like Bieber) using artistic license.

Comment: @Chenmunka  "I could not wait on you time enough ..." does not sound like "serve" to me, but be that as it may.  [The Select Works of Archbishop Leighton (1832)](https://books.google.com/books?id=NakrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA433&dq=%22wait+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVuIOG97zRAhXKzVQKHXPkAXU4FBDoAQhIMAg#v=onepage&q=%22wait%20on%22&f=false) "If thou hast begun to wait, faint not, give not up, wait on still. It were good reason, were it but upon little hope at length to find Him"

Comment: @Willow Rex  Last time I checked the Stones are all mostly over 70.  Funny they thought it was a reasonable phrase to use when apparently your younger generation *knew* it was not correct.   Look -- your explanation isn't incorrect, I only disagree with your assertion that "proper" English speakers don't use the phrase, when the usage has been around for centuries.

Comment: -1 for "it is slang/colloquial (but not yet 'correct')." Not correct according to...? Moreover, prepositions are flexible; I don't agree that "I am waiting _on_ the bus" can't mean you are waiting _for_ the bus. What about, "We are waiting on Jim. He said he'd be here at eight." Such a usage seems in line with [Macmillan's #2 definition for **wait on**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/wait-on). (Also, [Wordnik's entry from Wiktionary](http://www.wordnik.com/words/wait%20on) would also support such usages.) I can support "colloquial," but not "incorrect."

Comment: Do you understand what I meant by artistic license? Poetic license? It means that the artist can change the facts or use words for their own use. Advertisers do this often. :"Help us help you." Properly written it should be, "Help us *to* help you." However, we understand it. It is artistic license to make words work for the writer/poet/artist.

Comment: @J.R. I can also go find references that agree with my pov. [here is one as 'good' as wiktionary](http://www.grammarerrors.com/grammar/wait-onwait-for/) Suffice it to say, we disagree. Okay!

Comment: @WillowRex - That's a good link. Rather than debate this in comments, though, I'd rather see you add that link to your answer. If you changed your assertion that it's not correct to an observation that some regard it as incorrect (and then add that link), and I would happily change my downvote to an upvote!

Comment: @J.R.  as you wish! :wink: (please forgive my *The Princess Bride* quote, I could not resist.)

Comment: @Andrew. Give it up. You're wrong. Proper English speakers don't use the phrase.

Comment: @SimonH By all means, I admit your point may be correct.  However, I have provided references that say otherwise.  Perhaps you would also like to support your argument with something other than your say-so?

Comment: Andrew, no one is saying it is not in use. I hear it all the time. I also hear "yup",  "wha", and "What the...", this doesn't mean people do not use them or that we don't understand them.  I think perhaps your argument is with the word 'proper' or 'correct'. Common is not in discussion -- it is common.

Comment: @Andrew I'm sure we understand each other :-)  But I think the guy asking this question was looking to learn correct English before he moves onto the informalities (personally I don't know why as I can swear in a load of languages and I've always found it a lot more fun)

Answer (score 2):

As there seems to be a lot of debate in the comments on this I thought I should post [the Oxford Learner's Dictionary opinion](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wait-on) on this.

> **wait on somebody** | **wait on something**
>   *(informal, especially North American English)* to wait for something to happen before you do or decide something
>
> > She is waiting on the result of a blood test.

And by "informal" the OED means "suitable for normal conversation and writing to friends rather than for serious speech and letters".

Comment: "Or if you are an American, and you commonly speak what passes for *English* in those former colonies".  But all joking aside, this is a good example of a phrase which would pass unnoticed on one side of the Atlantic but get you funny looks on the other.  Unfortunately, English is widely spoken and there are many dialects.  Just do your best.

Comment: [This is the website](http://www.oed.com)  for the  OED or *Oxford English Dictionary*. Is this what you are citing or quoting?