# For More Than vs More Than For

Tags: word-order

I’ve been waiting for more than an hour for him.
I’ve been waiting more than for an hour for him.
Which is correct?

Comment: Neither are correct, because you have to use *have been **waiting***, not ***...waited***. There's nothing wrong with *optionally* omitting the preposition before ***more than an hour*** regardless of whether it comes before or after the other preposition-based adverbial clause: *I've been waiting [for] more than an hour for him.* But you *can't* omit the "primary" preposition before the indirect object *(**for** him)*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["I've been waiting for you for ages." vs "I've been waiting you for ages."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116879/ive-been-waiting-for-you-for-ages-vs-ive-been-waiting-you-for-ages)

Comment: Thanks. I’ve been waiting for more than an hour for him. I’ve been waiting more than for an hour for him. I’ve been waiting more than an hour for him. Are they correct? “For him” must be the last words right?

Comment: No. I said ***regardless** of whether it (**for more than an hour**) comes **before or after** the other preposition-based adverbial clause (**for him**)* above. There's nothing wrong with *I've been waiting **for him** [for] over an hour* - the only thing that's "fixed" is you ***must*** include the preposition before the indirect object (as also pointed out in the top answer to the linked question). But it's *optional* before ***over an hour***.

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes. I must include the preposition before the indirect object, so I can’t say “I’ve been waiting him for more than an hour, can I? I have another question. For over an hour, Over an hour, For more than an hour, More than an hour, are they all used as the same meaning?

Comment: **Yes!** Everything you say in your last comment is completely true! I'm only sorry I can't "explain" why you *must* include ***for*** before ***him***, but it's *optional* before ***over / more than an hour***. Anyway, well done for successfully editing out the irrelevant ***waited / waiting*** error. It's true I voted to close the question as a duplicate (because I think it *is*, and the answer you seek *has been* provided there) - but it's a good question, well enough presented, and it's not your fault you couldn't find that earlier question yourself, so I'll counterbalance the *downvote*.

Comment: Thank you very much.